# How to run scripts on Selenoid browser

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenoid

I have been trying to set up Selenoid for parallel testing purposes for my automation setup as I have hundreds of test cases to run.

Here's what I have tried.

**1) Installed Docker Desktop**

**2) Downloaded Selenoid containers using this command**

```
    docker run -d --name selenoid -p 4444:4444 -v ~/.aerokube/selenoid/:/etc/selenoid/:ro     
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock    
aerokube/selenoid:latest-release
```

**3) Selenoid and Selenoid UI are up and running on Docker.**
To check this setup I have done this:

When I type http://localhost:4444/status in my browser it takes me to a page with this text:

```
 {"total":5,"used":0,"queued":0,"pending":0,"browsers":{}}
```

When I type `http://localhost:8080/` in my browser. it takes me to Selenoid UI page with a text `No Sessions yet`.

I have a pulled chrome browser image using "docker pull selenoid/chrome" command.

When I try to automate a simple script to access this browser running on Selenoid container I am getting an error

```
 Requested environment is not available (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)



DesiredCapabilities dcap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
dcap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
dcap.setCapability("enableVNC", true);
dcap.setBrowserName("chrome");

RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
    URI.create("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub").toURL(), 
    dcap
);

String driverPath = "C:\\ABC\\chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);

// Get URL
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
// Print Title
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Am I missing anything important here? Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should at least create a `browsers.json` file inside `~/.aerokube/selenoid/` where Selenoid will read a list of available browser versions as well as Docker images to be used.

I would recommend you to use our automated installation tool called `cm` which will do all your actions above itself. Having this tool binary downloaded to your workstation installation would be as simple as issuing two commands:

```
$ ./cm selenoid start --vnc
$ ./cm selenoid-ui start
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I did. However for Chrome, I had to use "path": "/" instead of "path": "/wd/hub". in the browsers.json file. But it was clearly mentioned in the official documentation.Thanks for bringing up cm. It is much easier.

Comment: Specifying **browsers.json** using **-video-recorder-image** command line parameter, but isn't help. Still **NO SESSIONS YET :'(** on the page